# Error while exporting graphs from source code using joern

Tags: joern

I'm using joern with the command line functions, the following is my python script:

```
   parse_command = f"{joern_path}joern-parse {java_file} --output {output_path}/{file} "
   subprocess.call(parse_command, shell=True)
          
   export_command = f"{joern_path}joern-export {output_path}/{file} --out {output_path2_temp} --format {Format}  --repr {graph_type}"
   subprocess.call(export_command, shell=True)
```

The problem is, when I try to get the ASt graph type with any file format like json, xml (except  dot), it gives me the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.NotImplementedError: repr=Ast not yet supported for this format
    at io.joern.joerncli.JoernExport$.exportWithOdbFormat(JoernExport.scala:159)
    at io.joern.joerncli.JoernExport$.exportCpg(JoernExport.scala:111)
    at io.joern.joerncli.JoernExport$.$anonfun$main$2(JoernExport.scala:67)
    at io.joern.joerncli.JoernExport$.$anonfun$main$2$adapted(JoernExport.scala:66)
    at scala.util.Using$.resource(Using.scala:261)
    at io.joern.joerncli.JoernExport$.$anonfun$main$1(JoernExport.scala:66)
    at io.joern.joerncli.JoernExport$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(JoernExport.scala:61)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
    at io.joern.joerncli.JoernExport$.main(JoernExport.scala:61)
    at io.joern.joerncli.JoernExport.main(JoernExport.scala)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
```

Even though, in the documentation of joern they well said that it is adequate with any type of graph, and I'm using the last version of joern.